# Getting KeyError for Column Name in Pandas Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, delimiter, keyerror

I am reading a csv with pandas and then applying some basic functions to the columns. However I am getting a KeyError for the columnname (only 2 columns in my data frame). I have read other articles that suggest the column name has a whitespace in it but it does not. I have opened the file in notepad to verify and I am seeing nothing.

My thoughts are that my lineterminator argument in my read_csv call is causing something to be muddying my 2nd column name up.

```
C_Notes = pd.read_csv(r"Claims_Notes.csv", sep = ',', lineterminator = 
'\n', encoding="utf-8-sig") 

C_Notes['ClaimsNotes'] = C_Notes['ClaimsNotes'].apply(str.rstrip) ##KeyError
```

However, the below code works but it creates a new column titled the same as my 2nd column 'ClaimsNotes':

```
C_Notes['ClaimsNotes'] = C_Notes[C_Notes.columns[1]].apply(str.rstrip)
```

I must be missing something with the column names..

My error is simply KeyError: 'ClaimsNotes'

It must be something to do with the column headers but I cannot figure out why.

Thanks,

Comment: you can search for the error if you do `aList = list(C_Notes)` then you can compare it with `aList.get(0)== 'ClaimsNotes'` this should give you a answer if you have spelling problem or not (try 0 or 1 , depending which column it is)

Comment: other option just rename your colum headers by : `df.columns = ['a', 'b']`, where a and b gives you a new column name

Comment: Terrific. IT appears that the 2nd column it actually 'ClaimsNotes\r' . I am not sure why my read_csv is inserting a \r carriage return here... Any ideas?

Comment: the error that you have got is due to the minor bug in the code that you have written.

Comment: @user1241241 What bug?

Comment: bug that prevents the  code exactly in the way that we want it to function. If we change a bit, it will work for sure. @Coldchain9